# How do I disable "GroupBy" for searches via registry in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, c#

I'm building a tool to override the worst decisions Microsoft made for Windows which includes all things "group by". Thanks to a previous question, I have the registry arrangement used for the GroupBy in the downloads folder, but the same technique doesn't work for searches.

It doesn't seem that searches trigger a "bags" entry... or they do, but it doesn't actually affect anything. I was able to determine that the registry code that matches search results in Windows Explorer is "{7FDE1A1E-8B31-49A5-93B8-6BE14CFA4943}".

When I do a search and manually change the view to "group by", an entry is created in bags as follows:

[image: Windows disable group by for search]

Regardless of which folder I'm searching in or what values I change the group by to be (group by name, folder, date, etc), this entry doesn't change. Searching the rest of the registry doesn't yield any interesting results in the way of default values it might be pulling from.

The main issue here is that folder searches frequently show in "group by" view which is awful and dumb. I need to figure out how to programmatically disable it via registry.

Comment: My solution to your problem was to give up on the abhorrent "windows search" years ago and only use 3rd party tools now.  Yes, the *group by* by default makes an already poorly designed system (IMHO) even worse. Could [this tool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_bags_view.html) by NirSoft be helpful here to troubleshoot?  My personal guess is that the entire search is controlled by a ShellExtension (or extension functionality) and doesn't follow the rules of other explorer views.  The registry key created might be remnants of things it isn't even using.

Comment: Better search tools exist, such as [Voidtools Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) and [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/).

Comment: I appreciate the ideas, though what I'm trying to do is solve the problem for everyone, not just myself. Also, though I already use Agent Ransack (best tool ever), there are times I just want to filter the files in a single folder which works well enough other than being in that horrific "group by" mode.

Answer (score 0):

The key listed in my question IS correct, it's just that the registry values don't update on changes in Windows Explorer unless you re-run the search (which was messing up my testing).

Additionally, changes to the registry directly wouldn't reflect in the search results until after Windows Explorer was restarted.

So the solution was what I a had already: destroy any "bags" with the given key, add an "allfolders" default with group disabled, but with the new and final step of restarting Windows Explorer after the change.